# JS to toggle text and state in ToneJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tone.js

I have rarely used JS and cannot figure out why the text in the "play-stop-toggle" is not displaying.

My desired outcome is that:

1. [SOLVED] The text in `<div id="play-stop-toggle" onclick="togglePlay()">Play</div>` toggles between `PLAY` and `STOP` when you click it, and
2. Correspondingly, `Tone.Transport.stop()` and `Tone.Transport.start()` should toggle so that the sound in `var filter = new Tone.Filter` stops / starts playing.

Currently, the text will only toggle from PLAY to STOP on the first click, but it will not toggle back.  And no sound ever comes out.

```js
function togglePlay() {
  Tone.Transport.toggle();
  const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
  const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle");
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "STOP";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
  } else {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.start()
  }
}


var filter = new Tone.Filter({
  type: 'lowpass',
  Q: 12

}).toMaster()
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5em;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  /* text-align: center !important; */
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  margin: 0px;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: justify;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p.sig {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

div.bodycontent {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 375px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  /* background-color: #f44336; */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tone@13.8.25/build/Tone.js"></script>
  <script src="p1-fish.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ristyle.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bg">


    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Text</p>

  </div>

  <div id="play-stop-toggle" onclick="togglePlay()">Play</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On how your code is written, if `Tone.Transport.state` ever becomes "paused", you will always see `PLAY`. .... So the question is how does `Tone.Transport.toggle();` work?

Comment: You probably want to remove the first line - `Tone.Transport.toggle();`

Comment: @MoshFeu - Thanks! That solved the first problem of the text toggling back and forth.  But I am still stuck on how to trigger / untrigger the sound via that interaction.

Comment: I guess that it should work the same. But Since I'm not familiar with tone.js, please create a working example (jsbin, codesandbox etc.) so I'l try to debug it with you.

Comment: @MoshFeu - Thanks.  Here is a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xixugek/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Seems like the status is the right - https://jsbin.com/xiqidob/edit?html,css,js,output. If you ask about if the sounds getting play or not, please fix the example so the sounds will actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out no audio events were tied to the scheduler.  This JS solved my issue:

```
function togglePlay() {
  const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
  const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle");
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
  } else {
    element.innerText = "STOP";
    Tone.Transport.start()    
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#status').textContent = status;
}

var filter = new Tone.Filter({
  type: 'lowpass',
  Q: 12
}).toMaster()


var synth = new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster()

//create a loop
var loop = new Tone.Loop(function(time){
  synth.triggerAttackRelease("A1", "8n", time)
}, "2n")

//play the loop between 0-2m on the transport
loop.start(0)
```